# Worksheet_Change happening only once and Number Format not displaying in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

This worksheet change event happens once, and then it stops working. It is supposed to change the data based on a modifier (percentage), but it stops after changing once. Also, the number format is not working.  The formula bar is showing the correct numberformat, but the cell is not displaying the accounting format. Please send advice I have tried everything I can, but there have been no results.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim modifier As Range, i As Integer, j As Integer, R As Variant
Dim counter As Integer, SheetAddress As Worksheet, SheetName As String, SheetRange As Range, cell As Range
Dim startRng As Variant, EndRng As Variant, Brng As Range, t As Variant
'_____________________________________|PART 1 - In $ AMOUNT|________________________________________________
Set modifier = Range("E4:U29")

If Not Intersect(Target, modifier) Is Nothing Then
    counter = 1
    Do While counter <= 2
        For i = 4 To 28
            For j = 6 To 21
                'On Error Resume Next
                Dim rowcount As Variant
                SheetName = CStr(Cells(i, j).End(xlUp))
                Set SheetAddress = Sheets(SheetName)
                rowcount = SheetAddress.Range(SheetAddress.Cells(4, 2), SheetAddress.Cells(4, 2).End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
                For t = 4 To rowcount
                    If SheetAddress.Cells(t, 2) >= 27 And SheetAddress.Cells(t, 2) <= 51 Then
                        If IsEmpty(startRng) Then
                            startRng = SheetAddress.Cells(t, 2).Address
                        End If
                    End If
                    If SheetAddress.Cells(t, 2) <= 51 Then
                        EndRng = SheetAddress.Cells(t, 2).Address
                    End If
                Next t
                        
                Set SheetRange = SheetAddress.Range(startRng, EndRng)
                Dim offsetstart As Variant, offsetend As Variant
                offsetstart = SheetAddress.Range(startRng).Offset(0, 9)
                offsetend = SheetAddress.Range(EndRng).Offset(0, 9)
                
                'formula
                For Each cell In SheetRange
                    If cell.Value = Cells(i, "A") Then
                        Cells(i, j) = cell.Offset(0, 9) * Cells(i, "E")
                    End If
                Next cell
            Next j
        Next i
        counter = counter + 1
    Loop
End If

'column totals
For j = 6 To 21
    Cells(29, j) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(29, j).Offset(-25), Cells(29, j).Offset(-1)))
Next j

'grand total
Cells(29, "V") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("F29:U29"))
With Cells(29, "V")
    .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    .NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
End With


'_____________________________________|PART 2 - In UNITS (Hours)|___________________________________________
Dim startcell As Integer, endcell As Integer, Brange As Range
Set modifier = Range("E33:U58")

If Not Intersect(Target, modifier) Is Nothing Then
    counter = 1
    Do While counter <= 2
        For i = 33 To 57
            For j = 6 To 21
                On Error Resume Next
                SheetName = CStr(Cells(i, j).End(xlUp))
                Set SheetAddress = Sheets(SheetName)
                rowcount = SheetAddress.Range(SheetAddress.Cells(4, 2), SheetAddress.Cells(4, 2).End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
                For t = 4 To rowcount
                    If SheetAddress.Cells(t, 2) >= 27 And SheetAddress.Cells(t, 2) <= 51 Then
                        If IsEmpty(startRng) Then
                            startRng = SheetAddress.Cells(t, 2).Address
                        End If
                    End If
                    If SheetAddress.Cells(t, 2) <= 51 Then
                        EndRng = SheetAddress.Cells(t, 2).Address
                    End If
                Next t
                        
                Set SheetRange = SheetAddress.Range(startRng, EndRng)
                offsetstart = SheetAddress.Range(startRng).Offset(0, 9)
                offsetend = SheetAddress.Range(EndRng).Offset(0, 9)
                'formula
                For Each cell In SheetRange
                    If cell.Value = Cells(i, "A") Then
                        Cells(i, j) = cell.Offset(0, 8) * Cells(i, "E")
                    End If
                Next cell
            Next j
        Next i
    counter = counter + 1
    Loop
End If

Range(Cells(1, 6), Cells(1, 21)).EntireColumn.AutoFit

'column Totals
For j = 6 To 21
    Cells(58, j) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(58, j).Offset(-25), Cells(58, j).Offset(-1)))
Next j

'grand Total
Cells(58, "V") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("F58:U58"))
With Cells(58, "V")
    .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    .NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
End With



Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I don't know why it only works once. I think sometimes it has worked more than once, but it seems consistent with only one time. I feel like I have all the correct syntax with it, but it is not working. If there is anything else you can think to solve this please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure events are on by running `Application.EnableEvents = True` in the Immediate pane in the VB editor.  Also maybe comment out that `On Error Resume Next` or significantly reduce its scope, or you may be missing problems with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have Application.EnableEvents = False, which stops events from being called.

Comment: Yet there's an `Application.EnableEvents = True` right before `End Sub`?

Answer (score 0):

Remove all `On Error Resume Next`. Might be easier said than done, but it is the best way.
Put `On Error Goto` first in the Sub, like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Goto Worksheet_Change_ErrHandler
```

And close to the end, add this

```
Worksheet_Change_ErrHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Without this, and if something goes wrong (which it seems to do), you will end up with events disabled.
With an error handler that resets this, it won't leave you in this situation.